# What are the Niyats (in arabic) for different kinds of Salat?

Tags: salat

Assalamualaikum, everyone.
As the question mentions, what are the Niyats (in arabic), I have to make before standing in Salat. Please mention the niyats of the commonly performed Salats, such as: two rakats, three rakats (witr), four rakats or even one rakat (witr in another view) along with their meaning.

Comment: there is a book that mentions around 90 Niyahs for fard and Sunnah prayers.

Answer (score 4):

**For four raka'ats Prayer(Fard)**
***Pronunciation*:**

> “Nawayatu Aan Usallia Lillahi Taalaa Arbaa Rakaatee Salatil Ishaee
>   Faaradullahi Taala Ektadaaitu Bihazal Imami Mutaouuazzihan Ila Zihatil
>   Ka’batish Sharifati, Allahuu Akbar”

***Translation***:

> (I Headed for ALLAH Intent to Pray Isha’s 4 Rakat ALLAH Taala’s Fard
>   Prayer by Following This Imam Facing towards Kabah, ALLAH is Most
>   Great)

**For Two raka'ats Prayer(Fard)**
***Pronunciation:***

> “Nawayatu Aan Usallia Lillahi Taalaa Rakatai Salatil Fajree
>   Faaradullahi Taala Mutaouuazzihan Ila Zihatil Ka’batish Sharifati,
>   Allahuu Akbar”

***Translation:***

> (I Headed for ALLAH Intent to Pray Fajr’s 2 Rakat ALLAH Taala’s Fard
>   Prayer Facing towards Kabah, ALLAH is Most Great)

**For three raka'ats Prayer(Fard)**
***Pronunciation:***

> “Nawayatu Aan Usallia Lillahi Taalaa Salasa Rakaatee Salatil
>   Maaghribee Faaradullahi Taala Mutaouuazzihan Ila Zihatil Ka’batish
>   Sharifati, Allahuu Akbar”

***Translation***:

> (I Headed for ALLAH Intent to Pray Magrib’s 3 Rakat ALLAH Taala’s Fard
>   Prayer Facing towards Kabah, ALLAH is Most Great)

**For three raka'ats Prayer(Witr Waajib)**
***Pronunciation:***

> “Nawayatu Aan Usallia Lillahi Taalaa Salasa Rakaatee Salatil Witree
>   Wajibullahi Taala Mutaouuazzihan Ila Zihatil Ka’batish Sharifati,
>   Allahuu Akbar”

***Translation:***

> (I Headed for ALLAH Intent to Pray Witr’s 3 Rakat ALLAH Taala’s Waajib
>   Prayer Facing towards Kabah, ALLAH is Most Great)

For more details, see [here](http://blackbunker9.wordpress.com/2010/08/12/how-to-make-intention-to-pray-niyat/).